# How to add data to a SQL record with pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Hi I'm new to python/panda's.

I'm making a tool that matches data and saves it in a DB. I want to add data to the DB with to_sql() from sqlalchemy. If some of the data already exists in the database then it should add to the record. If data is completely new it should create a new record.

DB table example:

```
id, A, B, C, D, E
1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
2, 11, 12, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

If I have this dataframe below it should add data to where id=2

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [11], 'B': [12], 'C': [13], 'D': [14], 'E': [15]})
```

result:

```
id, A, B, C, D, E
1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

But if I have the dataframe below it should create a new record

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [16], 'B': [17], 'C': [13], 'D': [14], 'E': [15]})
```

result:

```
id, A, B, C, D, E
1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
2, 11, 12, NULL, NULL, NULL
3, 16, 17, 13, 14, 15
```

I've tried to use `df.to_sql('table', con=engine, if_exists='append'`), but it doesnt work.

I dont want to delete any data/records from the DB. It should only add. Can this be done with pandas/dataframe? Or should I just SQL query?

Comment: That's not what Pandas is for. It's not an ETL tool. It won't try to find if a record exists and update it. `to_sql` is meant to *save* the data to a table, the same way it would to a CSV file. It can either replace the table or INSERT the data.

Comment: That's too bad. So I should either use SQL or an ETL tool to do this?